# Allocation: Smart pointers and dynamically sized structure

Tags: c++

I've a structure that can be dynamically sized.
I want to use smart pointer (unique_ptr here) to allocate this structure.
The problem is that this struct is dynamically sized..

Here is the structure (of Windows library):

```cpp
typedef struct _STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO
{
    STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_VERSION Version;
    ULONG NumberEntries;
    union
    {
        STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_TYPE_1 Version1Entries[];
        STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_TYPE_2 Version2Entries[];
    };
} STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO, *PSTORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO;
```

I CAN get the total size of the structure.
So, I know i can do this with malloc:

```cpp
STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO *info = std::malloc(struct_size);
```

But I don't know how to allocate it with make_unique..

Comment: First off, `std::unique_ptr` does not “allocate”, it *manages* previously allocated memory. Secondly, there is currently no valid way in C++ to allocate such a structure. That said, a `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleter set to `std::free` should “work” here, to the same extent that using `std::malloc` “works”.

Comment: Ok so in cpp the only and clean way to work is to use malloc ?

Comment: It's not mine, this is the structure of Windows

Comment: @KonradRudolph `std::make_unique()` _does_ allocate for the user...

Comment: @underscore_d Right, of course it does — I read that as `unique_ptr`, somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use smart pointers with any allocator-deallocator pair by using a custom deallocation function. Here is an example using `std::malloc` and `std::free`:

```
struct freer
{
    void operator()(void* p) const noexcept {
        std::free(p);
    }
};

template<class T>
using unique_c_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, freer>;

template<class T>
[[nodiscard]] unique_c_ptr<T>
make_unique_malloc(std::size_t size) noexcept
{
    static_asset(std::is_trvial_v<T>);
    return unique_c_ptr<T>{static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(size))};
}


auto unique = make_unique_malloc<STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO>(struct_size);
```

---

> ```
> STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO_TYPE_1 Version1Entries[];
> ```

Array of unspecified bound cannot be a non-static member in C++, so this class is ill-formed. There is no such thing as "dynamically sized structure" in C++.

Given that it is from a system library, it probably relies on some language extension.

C language does have "flexible array members", but those are allowed only for structs; not for unions.

> ```
> STORAGE_DEPENDENCY_INFO *info = std::malloc(struct_size);
> ```

`std::malloc` returns a `void*` so this implicit conversion is also ill-formed in C++.

Comment: And to continue with nitpicking, `malloc` doesn't **construct** object, so until C++20, it is also unusable as-is.

Comment: @Jarod42 To nitpick the nitpick :) the change that you probably refer to (P0593) was accepted as a defect resolution against C++17, so to my understanding `std::malloc` should already be usable as it is in C.

Comment: I indeed referred to that. I though it was only available from C++20.